# Android Notification Badge Semantic

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

As far as I understand the default semantic of the [Android notification badge](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/badges) on app icons is "if there is a dot on the icon, you have unread notifications for that app". On certain devices like Samsung for example, the default badge is not just a dot but a number indicating the number of unread notifications.

What I would like to achieve is this: I would like to change the semantic of this badge number so that it shows the number of pending todo items inside my app. For that I would need to be able to

1. change the number from within my app and also via FCM but without showing any visible notification with a title and a body and
2. remove the badge when there are no more pending todo items left

As far as I understand both of those actions are not possible to do in Android.

In iOS this is not much of a problem and can easily be achieved. Is there any way to get the same effect in Android?